# Check if string starts with vowel

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

I am using a template for a text inputs and feedback messages to simplify my html code. This passes in variable string called `label` and populates the placeholder value for this input, and also uses the same string for the `invalid-feedback` message, but for the latter I want the correct a or an depending on if the `label` starts with a vowel or not. I currently use the `registerOnTouched()` function in `text-input-component.ts` as this is being called when the inputs are clicked/typed into to correct the feedback messages but I feel like there is a better solution/place to do this check.

Maybe something like a ternary operator or a pipe in the template?

And theoretically I could omit all the vowels except E from my check but that isn't future proof.

**Form:**

```
<app-text-input [formControl]="$any(loginForm.controls['email'])" [label]="'Email'" [type]="'email'"></app-text-input>
<app-text-input [formControl]="$any(loginForm.controls['password'])" [label]="'Password'" [type]="'password'"></app-text-input>
```

**Text-Input Template CSS:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input
    [class.is-invalid]="control.touched && control.invalid"
    type={{type}}
    class="form-control"
    [formControl]="control"
    placeholder={{label}}
  >
  <div *ngIf="control.errors?.['required']" class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a{{labelAfterVowelCheck}}</div>
</div>
```

**Text-Input Template TypeScript:**

```
import { Component, Input, Self } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, NgControl, PatternValidator } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-input',
  templateUrl: './text-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-input.component.css']
})
export class TextInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() label?: string;
  labelAfterVowelCheck = '';
  @Input() type: string = 'text';

  constructor(@Self() public ngControl: NgControl) {
    this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this; }
  writeValue(obj: any): void {
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.labelAfterVowelCheck = this.label!;
    if(["A","E","I","O","U","a","e","i","o","u"].some(vowel => this.label?.startsWith(vowel))){
      this.labelAfterVowelCheck = 'n ' + this.label;
    }
    else{
      this.labelAfterVowelCheck = ' ' + this.label;
    }
  }

  get control(): FormControl {
    return this.ngControl.control as FormControl;
  }
}
```

Comment: a**n** **h**onorable request, a**n h**our, **a u**sed car, **a o**ne-armed bandit. The rule you are implementing is not correct. You need to consider the phonetics, not the spelling of the input.

Comment: @Flater oof, that didn't even occur to me, realistically because I am the only one providing the input text, I could just define some constants for the ones that require the **n** and just take the hit when I need another one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a couple ideas:

1. I might separate out the "validation" into its own function, `isValid` here, but you can create a better name. ie.

```
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.labelAfterVowelCheck = this.label!;
    if(isValid(this.label)){
      this.labelAfterVowelCheck = 'n ' + this.label;
    }
    else{
      this.labelAfterVowelCheck = ' ' + this.label;
    }
  }
```

With this change, it's easier to see that you don't need the first assignment (as it will be redone in the line below below). And as you hint at, a ternary dries it up a little:

```
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.labelAfterVowelCheck = (isValid(this.label) ? 'n ' : ' ') + this.label;
  }
```

2. The validation itself can be simplified with a regular expression (although I get the sense this code is temporary). ie. `/^[aeiou]/i.exec(label)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. The first assignment was actually a remnant of some previous logic that I forgot was still there. I have gone for idea 1. Would you say it could be better to create my own pipe for this or is that getting to complex for what it is?